# Convert int64_t to NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsinteger

How can i convert int64_t to NSInteger in Objective-C ?

This method returns into score an int64_t* and I need to convert it to NSInteger:

```
[OFHighScoreService getPreviousHighScoreLocal:score forLeaderboard:leaderboardId];
```

Thank you.

Comment: 4 billion is not enough for highscore? That's an insane framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was on my code:

```
int64_t *score; 
[OFHighScoreService getPreviousHighScoreLocal:score forLeaderboard:leaderboardId];
NSLog(@"------------------------- %d", *score);
```

To work it should be:

```
int64_t score;  
[OFHighScoreService getPreviousHighScoreLocal:&score forLeaderboard:leaderboardId];
NSLog(@"------------------------- %qi", score);
```

And with this code i can obviously do:

```
NSInteger newScore = score;
```

Thank you.

Comment: This does not answer the question "Convert int64_t to NSInteger".

Answer (score 7):

They should be directly compatible on a 64-bit machine (or if you build with `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64`):

```
NSInteger i = *score;
```

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW16) indicates that the definition of `NSInteger` looks like this:

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

So on a 32-bit machine you might have some truncation issues to deal with.  On my machine here, this statement:

```
NSLog(@"%d %d", sizeof(int64_t), sizeof(NSInteger));
```

gives this output:

```
2010-03-19 12:30:18.161 app[30675:a0f] 8 8
```